# Issue matching exact word

Tags: regex

I am building a website validator regex that can match a url.

Thing is, it 90% works! It goes in and out of my string match which is where the issue is.

My regex: **(http(s?)://www.|www.|http(s?)://)+[a-z0-9]+([-.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(/.*)?**

My string to test with:

1)**(This should fail, but it passes)** https://www.xy

2)(This should pass, which it does) https://www.xy.com

It keeps going into my group (http(s?)://) instead of the group ((http(s?)://www.)

Any idea on how to solve this?

***URL i want to pass:***

http://www.test.com

http://test.com

https://test.com

https://www.test.com

***URL i want to fail:***
http://www.bla
https://www.ggg

So, if it matches https://www. or http://www. it should use the correct group and then apply the rest of the regex where it checks that it contains.. test.com or etc.

[image: This is using correct Group]
[image: This is using the wrong Group]

Comment: `http://www.bla`and `https://www.ggg` would be correct URLs if `bla` and `ggg` were existing TLDs. For example, `https://www.gg` or `https://www.xyz` are correct URLs

Comment: You most likely want to escape the `.` that comes before `[a-z]{2,5}` so that it only matches actual dots rather than any character (but as @Seblor said that will still make a poor URL validator)

Comment: Unless you want to capture the `s` in `https`, you don't need parentheses around it. Your main problem will be with handling all possible TLDs and rejecting others, because there are hundreds and it's a growing list.

Comment: If you're using a regex implementation that supports possessive quantifiers, `https?://(?:www.)?+[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(/.)?` looks like it would do what you want. If you're using a regex implementation that supports negative lookaheads `https?://(?:www.)?(?!www)[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(/.)?` would do the same (both make sure the `[a-z0-9]+` won't match the `www`)

Comment: @Aaron, seems to do the trick buddy!. See i understand what Seblor was saying, i know its possible .ggg or bla could be TLDs however i want to match it that if it includes http(s)://www. then the end user needs to finish the url with an extension such as test.com. Thanks Aaron!

Comment: I noticed two mistakes in my regexes : 1) in both regexes the `.` in `(?:www.)` should be escaped ; 2) in the second regex the negative lookahead should match the `.` too (also escaped) so that it doesn't prevent matching something like `http://wwwaaahhhooo.com`

Comment: @Aaron, is it possible to allow: www.test.com? So urls to start with "www.". You should answer the question and i will mark it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: I think you need https://regex101.com/r/pBVn0p/1 or https://regex101.com/r/pBVn0p/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes i think the second one: `https://regex101.com/r/pBVn0p/2` is the one i am looking for. Thing is, `www.test.c` or `www.test.` passes validation? Which it should fail

Comment: Just a sec, I will fix it.... Add `$` at the end

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Done :) Thanks again for the help pal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?!www\.[^.]+$)(?:www\.)?[a-z0-9]+(?:[-.][a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(?::[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pBVn0p/3)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:https?:\/\/)?` - an optional `http://` or `https://`
- `(?!www\.[^.]+$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if immediately to the right of the current position there is `www.` and then any 1+ chars other than dot to the end of the string
- `(?:www\.)?` - an optional `www.`
- `[a-z0-9]+` - 1+ lowercase letters and digits
- `(?:[-.][a-z0-9]+)*` -  0 or more repetitions of `-` or `.` and then 1+ lowercase letters and digits
- `\.` - a `.`
- `[a-z]{2,5}` - two to five lowercase letters
- `(?::[0-9]{1,5})?` - an optional sequence of `:` and 1 to 5 digits
- `(\/.*)?` - an optional sequence of `/` and the rest of the line
- `$` - end of the string.